# How to set session as cookie in soap request

Tags: spring-integration

I am using ws:outbound-gateway to call a soap web service which expects session id to be set in the cookie.

I am getting this session id in a request-callback of above ws-gateway.

I tried to enrich the header as below but that is adding soap header and not as the http header.

```
<int:chain id="login.session.extractor.chain"
          input-channel="login.ws.out" output-channel="login.gateway.out">
          <cic:xml-multi-node-extractor
                 path-selector="${login.session.path}" />
          <int:header-enricher>
                 <int:header name="COOKIE" expression="'JSESSIONID=' + payload['${login.session.path}']" />
          </int:header-enricher>
          <int:transformer expression="payload['payload']" />
   </int:chain>
```

I am expecting the session id to be set in the Cookie as below before making the call

```
DEBUG:>> "POST /api/v1/soap HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
DEBUG:>> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
DEBUG:>> "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
DEBUG:>> "SOAPAction: ""[\r][\n]"
DEBUG:>> "COOKIE: JSESSIONID=9F32328BDB000333E88AE8B7153B17FD.DC12BIZXSFAPI01[\r][\n]"
DEBUG:>> "User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1[\r][\n]"
DEBUG:>> "Host: api5.demo.eu[\r][\n]"
DEBUG:>> "Content-Length: 232[\r][\n]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anfortunatelly you can achieve it only with custom `MessageSender` for the `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>`:

```
public class CustomHttpComponentsMessageSender extends HttpComponentsMessageSender {

     @Override
     public WebServiceConnection createConnection(URI uri) throws IOException {
         String cookie = null;
         HttpComponentsConnection conn = (HttpComponentsConnection) super.createConnection(uri);
         HttpPost postMethod = conn.getHttpPost();
         cookie = "<Your Custom Cookie>";

         postMethod.addHeader("Cookie", cookie);

         return conn;
    }
}
```

---

Additional custom `WebServiceMessageCallback` might put the `message` to send to the `ThreadLocal` variable to get deal with `COOKIE` header from that `CustomHttpComponentsMessageSender`.

Comment: Thanks Artem for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with the other way which is using **interceptor** to the **ws-outbound-gateway** as below and this is pretty much working fine for me now. I am just looking if there is any configuration way of doing this than writing custom code.

```
public class HttpHeaderInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {

    public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext)
            throws WebServiceClientException {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext)
            throws WebServiceClientException {
        TransportContext context = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
        HttpUrlConnection connection = (HttpUrlConnection) context
                .getConnection();
        connection.getConnection().addRequestProperty("COOKIE",<custom value>);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext)
            throws WebServiceClientException {
        return true;
    }

}
```