# Adding custom header to MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway in SI

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Good evening,

I am trying to add custom header to a request but I am not too successful so far. I found examples which uses `Http.outboundGateway(...)` but I use `MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway`.

The following doesn't work, I cant see the header attributes in HTTP request.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow processRequest() {
    return flow -> flow.channel(INPUT_CHANNEL)
            .transform(requestMapper, "mapFrom")
            .enrichHeaders(
                    h -> h.header(X_TRANSACTION_ID, "somevalue")
                          .header(CLIENT_ID, "somevalue")
                          .header(CLIENT_SECRET, "somevalue")
            )
            .handle(webserviceOutboundGateway)
            .channel(OUTPUT_CHANNEL);
}
```

I don't know what I am missing. I'd appreciate any hint please.

Regards,
V.

+++++++++ UPDATE +++++++++

As per Artem's hint I crafted the following:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway muleMLGatewayWebserviceOutboundGateway(...) {
    MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway gateway = ...;
    gateway.setAdviceChain(Collections.singletonList(muleGatewayFailingAdvice()));
    gateway.setHeaderMapper(muleSecurityAttributesHeaderMapper());
    return gateway;
}

@Bean
public SoapHeaderMapper muleSecurityAttributesHeaderMapper() {
    return new MuleSecurityAttributesHeaderMapper();
}

class MuleSecurityAttributesHeaderMapper extends DefaultSoapHeaderMapper {

    @Override
    protected void populateUserDefinedHeader(String headerName, Object headerValue, SoapMessage soapMessage) {
        super.populateUserDefinedHeader(headerName, headerValue, soapMessage);
        MimeHeaders mimeHeaders = ((SaajSoapMessage)soapMessage).getSaajMessage().getMimeHeaders();
        mimeHeaders.setHeader("a", "b");
        setRequestHeaderNames("a");
    }
}
```

However I am still not finding the custom HTTP request header I am afraid.
Any thought please?

Comment: Have you looked at header mapping? https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ws.html#ws-message-headers

Comment: Thanks for the hint! If am not mistaken this doc is for setting the SOAP header, isn’t? However I need to add key-value pairs to the HTTP request header.

Comment: But it said over there explicitly: `Unless explicitly specified by the requestHeaderNames or replyHeaderNames properties of the DefaultSoapHeaderMapper, any user-defined SOAP headers are not copied to or from a SOAP Message.`

Comment: See @ArtemBilan's answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918019/how-to-set-session-as-cookie-in-soap-request

Comment: It also looks like you can subclass `SaajSoapMessageFactory` and override `postProcess` - it looks like that's where the default implementation adds an empty soap action header (if it is missing).

Comment: See also my answer.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell and Artem for the help! I seems what Gary recommended works, I created my `SaajSoapMessageFactory` class and now it works! Gary, if you could just add your sentence above as answer I'll accept it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can subclass `SaajSoapMessageFactory` and override postProcess - it looks like that's where the default implementation adds an empty soap action header (if it is missing).

You should probably also call the `super` method from the override.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to set the target transport headers (e.g. HTTP request) and not those SAOP envelop attributes, then you definitely need to look into a custom implementation of the `SoapHeaderMapper`, e.g. an extension of the `DefaultSoapHeaderMapper` where you need to override `populateUserDefinedHeader()`. Then you cast a `SoapMessage` into a `SaajSoapMessage` and do this:

```
MimeHeaders mimeHeaders = getSaajMessage().getMimeHeaders();
mimeHeaders.setHeader(headerName, headerValue);
```

And, of course, be sure to call a `setRequestHeaderNames()` with name you'd like to map to the request.

**UPDATE**

Your code must be like this:

class MuleSecurityAttributesHeaderMapper extends DefaultSoapHeaderMapper {

```
public MuleSecurityAttributesHeaderMapper() {
    setRequestHeaderNames(STANDARD_HEADER_NAMES, "a");
}

@Override
protected void populateUserDefinedHeader(String headerName, Object headerValue, SoapMessage soapMessage) {
    MimeHeaders mimeHeaders = ((SaajSoapMessage)soapMessage).getSaajMessage().getMimeHeaders();
    mimeHeaders.setHeader(headerName, headerValue.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Artem, thank you very much for your help! I edited my question, I still cant see my custom header unfortunately.

Comment: Looks like you are missing to set `setRequestHeaderNames()`. Since by default a `DefaultSoapHeaderMapper` doesn't map any end-user headers.

Comment: Thanks again! I tried to call `setRequestHeaderNames(...)` both in the overridden `populateUserDefinedHeader(...)` method and when my `SoapHeaderMapper` class is set to outbound gateway but no success.
However I could add the headers when created my `SaajSoapMessageFactory` as Gary recommended.

Comment: The `populateUserDefinedHeader()` is not called if there is no `setRequestHeaderNames()`. OK. I'll try to test that.

Comment: Yes. That works. Call `setRequestHeaderNames("a")` in the ctor of your `MuleSecurityAttributesHeaderMapper`.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.